# How to set WPF string format as percent wihout multiplying by 100?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a textbox bound to a property in an object.
I have setup the string format to  be p0.

However, when I enter 12 for example it is formatted as 1200% (multiplies by 100 and add % sign)

How can i set the stringformat so that for exampe 20 is formatted as 20% ?

My current control is :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyCase, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, StringFormat=p0}"/>
```

how t change the string format so that the format for 7 is 7% not 700% ?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
"{Binding Path=Percentage, StringFormat={}{0}%}"
```

Comment: Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790975/format-decimal-for-percentage-values I have the same issue, but I do want to multiply the value by 100 for the representation since I store the percentage values in a decimal col.

Comment: Note: You can add a format string to this syntax, just add a ':' followed by your format ('C', 'F6', "#.####", etc.)
ex. {}{0:0.00}% for 82.345 displays 82.35%

For details see: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: In Silverlight 5 I'm getting a "Unexpected Token after end of Markup Extension." error. Any tip?

Comment: This how achieved the same result in Silverlight 5 Binding="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat='\{0:n2\}%'}"

Comment: Thx @ShimmyWeitzhandler StringFormat={}{0:P2}

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to wrap the `%` in single quotes, and put it inside the curley brackets:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Percentage, StringFormat={}{0:#0.00'%'}}"/>
```