# Apply Excel Custom Formatting in C# string format

Tags: c#, excel

Currently I am working in excel add-in based C# application. I have to read the excel cell value and apply same Custom format to other string data in C# application.

For example, I have the following custom formatting.

```
 #,##0.0_);(#,##0.0);#,##0.0_);@_) --> Numeric Data Formatting

 $#,##0.0_);($#,##0.0);$#,##0.0_);@_) --> Currency Data Formatting

 0.0%_);(0.0%);0.0%_);@_)  --> Percentage Data Formatting
```

How can I apply this number formatting in .Net string objects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790975/format-decimal-for-percentage-values

Comment: Custom Data Formatting has different number formatting. I don't know how and when to use which string format in this semi-colon separated number format string.

Comment: I am asking how to interpret and apply Excel Custom format in .NET string objects.

Comment: Good reference here: http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/CustomFormats.htm You will need to take this information and use it to apply the equivalent formatting in .NET, though note that some of the formats may not map directly, and some (such as color formatting) have no equivalents in .NET