# String.Format putting % sign after value

Tags: asp.net

I have a `decimal` column in my Database where values are stored as 30.49 etc...

In my `GridView` I want to show decimal column with % sign.  I am trying to use String.Format for this but it seems not to working.  I tried every possible option available but still not getting what I want.

Here is what I want: `30.49%`

This is what I've tried:

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#String.Format("{0:#,0.########}",Eval("columnname")) %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format decimal for percentage values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790975/format-decimal-for-percentage-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("columnname")+"%"%>'></asp:Label>
```