# How to display a decimal as a % in C#

Tags: c#, sql

There could be 2 ways to fix this. I am not sure what is the easiest and not sure how to go about it. I want to display a % for completeness. When 1 record is counted and completed is 1 I have a decimal of 1.0000000000000. which would be 100%. I do not think I need all the zeros but it may not be a factor. My question is how do I either convert this in C# as a % or can I do this in SQL with the code I already have in place.

I created a SQL View to display counts of records, Number of records total and number of records completed. then divide the two of them to get percentage, or in this case a decimal.

```
SELECT
    TaskId,
    Description,
    Priority,
    IsCompleted,
    CreatedDate,
    CASE WHEN CompletedCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (CAST(TaskCount AS NUMERIC(12, 2))) / (CAST(CompletedCount AS NUMERIC(12, 2))) END AS CompletePct,
    TaskCount,
    CompletedCount
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            dbo.Tasks.TaskId,
            dbo.Tasks.Description,
            dbo.Tasks.Priority,
            dbo.Tasks.IsCompleted,
            dbo.Tasks.CreatedDate,
            (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(TaskDetailId) AS Expr1
                FROM
                    dbo.TaskDetails
                WHERE
                    (TaskId = dbo.Tasks.TaskId)
            ) AS TaskCount,
            (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(TaskDetailId) AS Expr1
                FROM
                    dbo.TaskDetails AS TaskDetails_2
                WHERE
                    (
                        IsComplete = 'true'
                        AND TaskId = dbo.Tasks.TaskId
                    )
            ) AS CompletedCount
        FROM
            dbo.Tasks
            INNER JOIN dbo.TaskDetails AS TaskDetails_1 ON dbo.Tasks.TaskId = TaskDetails_1.TaskId
        GROUP BY
            dbo.Tasks.TaskId,
            dbo.Tasks.Description,
            dbo.Tasks.Priority,
            dbo.Tasks.IsCompleted,
            dbo.Tasks.CreatedDate
    ) AS q1
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790975/format-decimal-for-percentage-values

Comment: Does `* 100.0` solve your problem?

Comment: This code makes little sense: 1. Why the join on `TaskDetails` on the outside, you don't use it and just have to remove it with a `group by` 2. You could combine those two subqueries with conditional aggregation 3. Why the outermost subquery `q1` it doesn't do anything

Comment: Address all the display tasks to your application, not the database layer. This is more flexible and supportable way.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to format things in the font-end because…

- Different users can use the same application using different cultures.
- Different applications can access the same DB and format things differently.
- The same application can format things differently in different contexts (e.g., in a UI grid versus on a printed report)
- Modern programming languages (as C#) and libraries (as .NET BCL) have generally a better support for predefined and custom formatting and for writing your own formatting logic. You can use OOP concepts, pattern matching, string interpolation and data types not available in SQL (Booleans, arrays, dictionaries). SQL on the other side has not evolved very much since the times of Fortran and Cobol.
- You have better support for testing, debugging, version control, refactoring, code analysis and coding assistance (IntelliSense, code snippets).
- Maintenance and deployment are easier.
- If you want to use the returned values to do further calculations, create charts or to re-format them in a different way, values formatted in SQL require you to parse them back to a numeric type. You might lose precision and introduce errors due to culture specific issues.

In .NET you can use [The Percent ("P") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-percent-p-format-specifier) to format a decimal as percent.

Answer (score -1):

Well I'm not sure what's the issue but, the percent is the product of the decimal by 100. To remove de decimal part either cast the double to int or use the Math.floor function in it.

Comment: Or use the round function, especially if you want some places after the decimal but not all.

Comment: This view is just for Viewing purposes. The .chtml page populates a Foreach record. The SQL view gives me the graphics that I need. So the % is only used to show the Graph of the progress bar % - meaning that column is put in the width of the style. The rest of the code works fine.

Answer (score -1):

So i decided to do the multiplication of * 100 in SQL query. Working code is below..

```
SELECT        
 TaskId, 
 Description, 
 Priority, 
 IsCompleted,  
 CreatedDate, 
 CASE WHEN CompletedCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (CAST(((CAST(CompletedCount AS NUMERIC(12, 2))) / (CAST(TaskCount AS NUMERIC(12, 2))) * 100) AS INT)) 
                         END AS CompletePct, TaskCount, CompletedCount
FROM            
(
 SELECT        
  dbo.Tasks.TaskId, 
  dbo.Tasks.Description, 
  dbo.Tasks.Priority,  
  dbo.Tasks.IsCompleted, 
  dbo.Tasks.CreatedDate,
  (
       SELECT        
         COUNT(TaskDetailId) AS Expr1
       FROM    
         dbo.TaskDetails
       WHERE  
         (TaskId = dbo.Tasks.TaskId)
  ) AS TaskCount,
  (
       SELECT        
          COUNT(TaskDetailId) AS Expr1
       FROM            
          dbo.TaskDetails AS TaskDetails_2
       WHERE        
         (IsComplete = 'true') 
       AND 
         (TaskId = dbo.Tasks.TaskId)
  ) AS CompletedCount
   FROM            
       dbo.Tasks 
       INNER JOIN dbo.TaskDetails AS TaskDetails_1 ON dbo.Tasks.TaskId = TaskDetails_1.TaskId
   GROUP BY 
       dbo.Tasks.TaskId, dbo.Tasks.Description, dbo.Tasks.Priority, dbo.Tasks.IsCompleted, dbo.Tasks.CreatedDate) AS q1
```