# Entering percentage into text box multiplies value by 100

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, prism

I've got the following text box in my Silverlight app:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Model.PercentOfSale, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=p}"/>
```

where `PercentOfSale` is defined as a `double`.

The display in the text box is as expected:

> 0.00 %

However, when I enter a new value (say 15) I get:

> 1,500.00 %

So the value is being multiplied up by 100 (incorrectly).

My users aren't going to want to enter 0.15 as the value, so what do I need to do to get it to accept 15 as 15% and not 1,500%?

I've seen other questions here like

[How to set WPF string format as percent wihout multiplying by 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1283049/59303)
[Format decimal for percentage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1790975/59303)

But the solutions given don't work for me.

Comment: Maybe you should divide your user inputs by 100 instead. Storing 15% as 0.15 has many benefits. And msdn is clear about the value being multiplied by 100, so it doesn't look _incorrect_ to me. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierPct

Comment: @Nicolas - I guess I was expecting a value I entered to be divided by 100 for me, but maybe I'm being naive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using Converters?
If you don't want to change input values than you can convert then.
[Here is example](http://www.go4answers.com/Example/element-element-binding-connect-two-172631.aspx) of converters usage.

Comment: I am thinking of a converter, but I was expecting this to happen "automatically" as I've specified a formatter.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up changing the Property's setter so that it modified the value:

```
private decimal percentOfSale;
public decimal PercentOfSale
{
    get
    {
        return percentOfSale;
    }
    set
    {
        percentOfSale = value / 100;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("PercentOfSale");
    }
}
```

So my XAML becomes:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PercentOfSale, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=p}"/>
```

and when I load my model I have:

```
this.percentOfSale = Model.PercentOfSale;
```

note the lower case "p" - this avoids the scaling on the initial setup so that the `StringFormat` in the binding works correctly and when the value is set from the UI it also scales.

Then when I want to save the data I have:

```
Model.PercentOfSale = this.percentOfSale;
```

---

I actually found that the percentages were being stored as values from 0 to 100 (not 0 to 1) - it's not my data model & I should have checked first, so this mean I need to scale the value on initial setup:

```
this.PercentOfSale = Model.PercentOfSale;
```

Note the upper case "P".

and on saving:

```
Model.PercentOfSale = this.percentOfSale * 100;
```

to bring it back into line with the data as stored in the database.