# Label % suffix in binding

Tags: wpf, string-formatting

I found something like this:
[How to set WPF string format as percent wihout multiplying by 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283049/how-to-set-wpf-string-format-as-percent-wihout-multiplying-by-100)

I just want to have a '%' sign suffix after my number. my code looks like this

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=ReportGridViewModel.FillingDegree, StringFormat=P}" />
```

I already tried this one too

```
<Label Content="{Binding ReportGridViewModel.Cgi, StringFormat={}{0}%}" />
```

in both cases I don't see any changes like I don't have any stringformat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StringFormat` property of a `Binding` is only applied when the target property is of type `String`. In a `Label`, the target property `Content`, is of type `Object`, so `StringFormat` is not respected.

To get this to work in a label, use `ContentStringFormat`. If you were to use a `TextBlock`, you could use the `StringFormat` provided by `Binding`.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of `Label` you need to use the [ContentStringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat.aspx) property

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=ReportGridViewModel.FillingDegree}" 
       ContentStringFormat="P" />
```