# c# wpf textbox - adding a text to input TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, events, textbox

I want to add percent sign "%" to any input text in wpf TextBox when the user insert a text.

So when the user will enter a number, will be added % sign to any number in the input box, 
for example: 5 will shown at the Text box as 5%
0 - 0%
100 - 100%

I tried the following code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxInputValue" Text="{Binding AddPercentSign, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat={}{0}%}" Style="{StaticResource @TextBoxStyle}" Width="100" Height="20"></TextBox>
```

and:

```
public int AddPercentSign{ get; set; }
```

and:

```
TextBoxInputValue.DataContext = this;
```

But it has no effect on the TextBox when the user insert an input...

How can I achieve that result?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use a flag that decides whether you should actually set the `Text` property in the event handler:

```
private bool _handleEvent = true;
private void TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_handleEvent)
    {
        _handleEvent = false;
        MyTextBox.Text = MyTextBox.Text + "%$#";
        _handleEvent = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is working... But not quiet as I exepted... I have edited my question

Comment: Can't you just change the code to: MyTextBox.Text = MyTextBox.Text + "%"; ?

Comment: No cause then when the user insert for example 12345 I get: 12345%%%%%

Comment: Try to bind to an int/double/decimal property use a StringFormat as suggested by @Mike Eason then. And please don't change your original question completely once it has been answered. Ask a new question if you have another issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **binding** your `Text` property, you can use `StringFormat`.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty, StringFormat={}{0}%}" />
```

Check out [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/the-stringformat-property/) tutorial.

Comment: I tried adding: "{Binding Path=Percentage, StringFormat={}{0}%}" as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283049/how-to-set-wpf-string-format-as-percent-wihout-multiplying-by-100 but it is doing nothing to my TextBox input... I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

> But it has no effect on the TextBox when the user insert an input...

You need to define the source property and set the `DataContext` of the `TextBox` to the class where it is defined, e.g.:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding SomeProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat='{}{0}%'}" />
```

---

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.DataContext = this;
    }

    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you really add the AddPercentSign property to the same class where the TextBoxInputValue is defined? If you don't see a value in the TextBox the binding doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I have added this: public int AddPercentSign{ get; set; } to the same class

Comment: Could you please post your entire code-behind file?

Comment: It's a huge file... from the other side can you share an example of working code that does this job? of adding % sign to any text insert into TextBox

Comment: I already did. It is just that you cannot seem to apply it to your code. That's why I need to see your code it in order to be able to tell you what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link, even I was facing somewhat similar problem
Solution in this link can me modified according to your condition.

[Add percent sign "%" to any input text in wpf TextBox when the user insert a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71826361/add-sign-in-starting-and-end-of-textbox-as-well-as-format-value-as-comma-separ)